# Where to (legally) download Windows iso directly instead of using their .exe utility?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, iso

Recently, I installed Windows onto a bootcamp partition on my MBP by using an .iso image file of Windows that I downloaded directly from one of Microsoft's official websites (maybe it was www.microsoftstore.com or windows.microsoft.com) and yes, I used a license key legally purchased from the Microsoft store.

I'm trying to find the link to download the .iso file directly again but I can't seem to find it after much searching.  *Does anyone know where to download the straight-up .iso image of Windows? (Legally of course!)*

**Please note:  I'm not asking for the link to the .exe downloader that downloads the media for you.**  I already have access to that in the digital content section of my order history at microsoftstore.com.  I'm asking for the link on Microsoft's site that provides the .iso directly.  I can't remember how I found the link to it, but it might have been in a cnet article or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah.  After searching for an hour, I finally found the link just minutes after I posted this question.  Go figure.  You can get the Windows 10 .iso here after answering a few questions:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: Welcome to the site :) . You can probably go ahead and mark this one solved, if you like.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will do so as soon as the site lets me (2 days from now it says).

Comment: @user45183 Please mark this as the correct answer, since no one has posted another option. :)